# Cant make a button activity on tabbed activity

Tags: android

I've been tried to make a scouting app with a tabbed activity but I cant make button action,i need to make onclicklistener to a button but I get error

> Error:(32, 9) error: unreachable statement"

Tab3Teleop.java:

```
package com.example.itai.scoutingapollo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Itai on 10/03/2017.
 */

public class Tab3Teleop  extends Fragment {


    TextView CornerTV, VortexTV;
    Button PlusCorner, MinusCorner, MinusVortex, PlusVortex;

    int TV1 = 0;




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
        //TODO slide to position

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3teleop, container, false);
        return rootView;
        CornerTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CornerTV);
        VortexTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.VortexTV);
        PlusVortex = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlusVortex);
        PlusCorner = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlusCorner);
        MinusCorner = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MinusCorner);
        MinusVortex = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MinusVortex);

        PlusCorner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CornerTV.setText(TV1 + 1);
            }
        });
        return rootView;

    }









}
```

And this the MainActivity:

```
package com.example.itai.scoutingapollo;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Scouting Saved", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });








    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {


                case 0:
                    Tab1Setup tab1 = new Tab1Setup();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    Tab2Auto tab2 = new Tab2Auto();
                     return tab2;
                case 2:
                    Tab3Teleop tab3 = new Tab3Teleop();
                    return tab3;
                case 3:
                    Tab4End tab4 = new Tab4End();
                    return tab4;
                default:
                    return null;

            }




        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            //TODO set slides number
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {

                //TODO set slides names
                case 0:
                    return "Setup";
                case 1:
                    return "Auto";
                case 2:
                    return "Teleop";
                case 3:
                    return "End";
            }
            return null;
        }




    }
}
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhKzd.png)

Hope you can help... thanks.

Comment: You can't place code after a `return`

Comment: Thank you,  Its solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the unnecessary return statement:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
    //TODO slide to position

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3teleop, container, false);
    //Remove this:
    //return rootView;
    CornerTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CornerTV);
    VortexTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.VortexTV);
    PlusVortex = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlusVortex);
    PlusCorner = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlusCorner);
    MinusCorner = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MinusCorner);
    MinusVortex = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MinusVortex);

    PlusCorner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CornerTV.setText(TV1 + 1);
        }
    });
    return rootView;

}
```